# argparse claims argument althoug default value specified

Tags: python, argparse

I wrote

```
parser.add_argument("n_tasks", default=20, help='Number of tasks to start')
```

and was expecting, that absense of argument will default it to `20`. Althoug it writes

```
usage: get_sentinel_spawner.py [-h] n_tasks
get_sentinel_spawner.py: error: the following arguments are required: n_tasks
```

why?

Comment: You are defining a positional argument. By default, they are required arguments. However, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) does say that `nargs='?'` should make a positional argument optional. However, I'm unsure what happens to the order of the arguments if such a positional argument is in the middle. I would have those kinds of arguments at the very end of the list.

Comment: You could also turn it into an optional argument by putting a double dash in front of the name, like so: `parser.add_argument("--n_tasks", default=20, help='Number of tasks to start')`